# writing update function to check before adding data in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

hi I want to write an update function to check the data in my database and if there was a similar column don't add the filed update that filed

here in the code below, I deserialize JSON file

```
 public class CustomerDeserializer
    {

            public static List<DtoCustomer> Deserialize()
            {

                List<DtoCustomer> result =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DtoCustomer>>(
                        File.ReadAllText(@"Information.json"));
                return result;
            }
        }
```

in this part, I read the data and build it

```
 public static Customer CustomerBuild(DtoCustomer dto)
        {
              return new Customer()
                {
                    FirstName = dto.FirstName,
                    LastName = dto.LastName,
                    Address = dto.Address,
                    Email = dto.Email,
                    ComapnyName = dto.CompanyName,
                    PhoneNumber = dto.Phone

                };
```

and then I process data and save them into database

////update function

```
  public static void Process(Customer customer)
            {
                using (var context = new PracticeEntities1())
                {
                    context.Customers.Add(customer);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

I want to write an update function before saving to check the data and update it what should I do?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. 
What fields do you want to check?

Comment: hi I want to check if data is in the database don't save it update that data

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like this:

```
    using (var context = new PracticeEntities1())
    {
        var existingCustomer = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email == customer.Email);

        if (existingCustomer != null) {
            existingCustomer.FirstName = customer.FirstName;
            existingCustomer.LastName = customer.LastName;
            existingCustomer.Address = customer.Address;
            existingCustomer.CompanyName = customer.CompanyName;
            existingCustomer.Phone = customer.Phone;
        }
        else
        {     
            context.Customers.Add(customer);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```